# display text in each leaf when parent is focused d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to display text in leaf when parent is focused like this: http://i60.tinypic.com/25qxdzt.jpg. Here is my code which display text only when last parent is focused:

```
 var text = svg.selectAll("text")
     .data(nodes)
     .enter().append("text")
     .attr("class", "label")
     .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
     .style("display", function(d) { return d.children ? null : "none"; })
     .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Comment: You would need to run like the above in a click handler or whatever you're using to focus a node.

Comment: Thanks. I sloved it with tooltips.